# Why does my laptop wake up in the night to hibernate?

Tags: windows-7, sleep, hibernate

I have Win7 64bit and I have it set to sleep when I close the lid.  If I open it a few hours after closing (in the evening after work) it wakes from sleep, however when I turn it on again in the morning it always resumes from hibernation.  This implies it is waking in the night and then hibernating.

Why does it do this and how can I stop it so that it will be waking from sleep in the morning?

It always has 90%+ battery in the morning so its not like it is thinking it might not be able to sustain sleep much longer so hibernates to avoid losing work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the exact same situation, only with Windows 7 32-bit.  What happens is that the computer is set to sleep for a certain time, and then hibernate after that...this happens even on AC power...My recommendation is to change your power settings so that sleep lasts longer.  Hope that helps!

Comment: you mean change the value of Power Options->sleep->Hibernate after->on battery to Never or to some very large value?

Comment: @Sam: exactly.  but it might drain your battery given long enough...

Comment: presumably if I have a setting for Power options->Battery->low power action=hibernate then when it gets to low power threshold whilst sleeping, it will wake up and hibernate?

Comment: yup, probably...

Comment: thanks studio hack.  this morning, opened the lid and it woke from sleep, not from hibernation!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have scheduled events that get triggered even though the machine is 'asleep'? If these are running, and you have a setting to hibernate after some period of inactivity, that would cause this behaviour.

Test it out -- schedule some event and close the lid. See if the machine wakes.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my laptop was going into hibernate even though I was asking for it to stay in sleep mode longer. After generating powercfg /SYSTEMPOWERREPORT I noticed Drain (dozed to hibernate because the standby battery budget was exceeded). After searching this came up this https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/customize/power-settings/adaptive-hibernate which basically states that windows will transition to hibernate once a certain amount of battery is drained (even if the hibernate timer has not kicked in) Apparently this is powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_presence standbybudgetpercent 60 will increase that percentage to 60% (or set it to a value that you think is appropriate)